# VM doesn't pick up ip from dhcp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, ip

I'm running virtualbox in bridged mode on a windows host.

`ifconfig` returns this:

[image]

Here's the `etc../interfaces file`:

[image]

**How can I force it to grab an IP address from the `dhcp`?**

Comment: Please don't post pretty much the same question twice.

Comment: Have you tried setting allow-hotplug eth1? Restart network afterwards. If it's bridged, do you have a running DHCP server in that network? Try running dhclient -v eth1, you should see the DHCP request/ack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just un installed and installed DHCP and it working beautifully.. If you mess up with dns ot the ip adress of the dns server while dhcp is installed.. Just uninstall it and all is well